# Two-lined divider becomes invisible if height is lesser then 4dp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to have divider view which consists of two parallel lines - white and grey ones. I've found xml on SO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <size android:height="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <size android:height="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

then I'm using it like this:

```
<View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider" />
```

But it doesn't show anything. I've found that my view is visible only if I set height of 4dp or greater. But this is not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Well I can use two views with background="@android:color/white or darker_grey" but I want two achieve the same effect using just one drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the shape to a rectangle works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="1dp">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <size android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <size android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Not working. Also notice that I'm not using this view as listDivider. It is just a part of another layout.

Comment: All other views within the same parent has layout_height="wrap_content". But why it is visible with layout_height="4dp" or greater?

Comment: Hi - changing it to a rectangle works for me. Maybe something with 2 lines and a layer-list and padding, I'm not sure. But I can set this in the view at 2dp. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
         <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
```